# Django: Signal on queryset.update

Tags: django, django-signals

Django is sending the pre/post_delete signals if you are using the `queryset.delete()` method, but shouldn't it then also send pre/post_save on `queryset.update()`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps it should, but it doesn't. `.update()` does not call the `.save()` method on the individual objects in the QuerySet, and instead updates the all in a single SQL call (UPDATE, as it happens). Since it doesn't use `.save()`, it would be inconsistent for it to call the pre- and post-save signals. I can certainly envision use-cases in which one might want it to do so, but I can also envision cases in which one wouldn't. It seems to me that not calling the pre- and post-save signals is the correct behavior here as it leaves more flexibility for the programmer. It's not hard to trigger those signals manually, and I think it's definitely a better design decision to ask programmers to remember to trigger the signals to get desired behavior than asking them to remember to disconnect the signals to avoid undesired behavior.

Comment: Well though the reasons mentioned I think this is somehow inconsistent behaviour, because the queryset.delete() method also doesnt call delete() on the single instances, but it send the same signals as model.delete() does!

Comment: Also, in order to be able to send a save-related signals on a queryset, they'd essentially need to do a select for the elements in addition to the update, eliminating the benefits of having a bulk update method.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, `.update()` can be used to prevent a signal dispatch, for example if you wanna update an instance without firing a signal you should use it and not the `.save()` method.